# jQuery "AD Gallery" inside a Popup Window

Tags: jquery, popup, gallery

I have a very simple page layout. The HTML code for the gallery is like this:

```
<div id="myGalleries">
    <p class="myClass"><a href="#">Gallery One</a></p>
    <p class="myClass"><a href="#">Gallery Two</a></p>
    <p class="myClass"><a href="#">Gallery Three</a></p>
    <p class="myClass"><a href="#">Gallery Four</a></p>
</div>
```

Each link represents a small amount of images for that gallery.

When the user click in one of the links, I need to open a window with the respective photos
of that gallery. Is it possible to do so using [AD Gallery](http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/), for example? I'd like to open "AD Gallery" inside the window.

Or.... is there any other jQuery plugin to do this all by itself?

Thanks in advance,

H.

Answer (score 0):

There is an AD-Gallery example of this here:

http://www.hanslipasphalting.co.uk/portfolio.htm

The 2nd, 3rd and 5th 'View Slideshow' links show a JQuery UI Dialog containing an AD-Gallery Slideshow.  The only manual fix required was to manually set the width of the thumbnail list which can be seen in the portfolio.js file.